# Entity Framework 4.1: code first - Foreign key restriction error

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco

I have a base class, let me call, Entity_A which only has a property 'ID' that is the primarky key.

```
public abstract class Entity_A
{
   [Key(), Required]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public Guid ID { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have two other classes, Entity_B and Entity_C.

Entity_B and Entity_C inhertis from Entity_A:

Scenario #1:

```
[Table("Entity_B")]
public class Entity_B : Entity_A
{
    [Required]
    public virtual string propertyB1 { get; set; }

    // Below foreign key
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("propertyB2")]
    public virtual Guid propertyB2Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Entity_C propertyB2 { get; set; }
}

[Table("Entity_C")]
public class Entity_C : Entity_A
{
    [Required]
    public virtual string propertyC1 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string propertyC2 { get; set; }
}
```

It works ok, it creates the tables. My problem is when I remove Entity_A and I put 'ID' property within each class Entity_B and Entity_C:

Scenario #2:

```
[Table("Entity_B")]
public class Entity_B
{
    [Key(), Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string propertyB1 { get; set; }

    // Below foreign key
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("propertyB2")]
    public virtual Guid propertyB2Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Entity_C propertyB2 { get; set; }
}

[Table("Entity_C")]
public class Entity_C
{
    [Key(), Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string propertyC1 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string propertyC2 { get; set; }
}
```

When I execute, an exception is raised:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'Entity_B_propertyB2' on table 'Entity_B' may
cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO 
ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint. See 
previous errors.
```

I solve it by overriding OnModelCreating method:

```
// TURN OFF ON DELETE CASCADE GLOBALY BY REMOVING THE CONVENTION 
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();  
}
```

My question are:

1) Why Entity Framework behaviour is different from scenario #1 (where it works) to scenario #2 (where it does not work)?

2) Why in scenario #2 is not working if I do not turn off on delete cascade convention?
   If I turn it off, is it a good practice? I wonder if it is bad or good. Also, Is there a way to make it works without the need of overriding OnModelCreating?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you explain why your property named `Entity_B_Id` is returning type `Entity_C`?  That seems like a strange name for it and I want to make sure I understand what you're trying to do.  Thanks!

Comment: What relationship are you intending between the entities? Is Entity_C required or optional? Would I also be correct in assuming you'd want the ID on Entity_C to be both primary key and foreign key to the ID on Entity_B?

Comment: Hi all, I have modified the post to be more detailed. Sorry!

Comment: Mark: .... to the ID on Entity_B not. to the propertyB2Id on Entity_B. See my new post edited. Entity_C is required.

Comment: The problem is somewhere else. In scenario 2 is no multiple cascading delete path. There is only a single one-to-many relationship. Maybe you have removed something from the classes for this post and there are other entities in your model with relationships to `Entity_B` and `Entity_C`?